# A recipe for putting a subversion checkout under mercurial version control

Tags: svn, version-control, mercurial, dvcs

Can someone point me to a recipe for creating a Mercurial repos from a Subversion checkout
by recursively adding all files except those in .svn directories?
I imagine it looks something like `hg add --exclude PATTERN` for some pattern like `.svn`.

Does a Subversion checkout have any "special" files besides those in the .svn directories?
If so, I'll need the recipe to to exclude those too. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easiest way is to do a Subversion export rather than a checkout, then you just get the directory structure you want, without the .svn folders.

If you have to use a checkout, then add this to a file in the root called `.hgignore` before you add to Mercurial:

```
syntax: glob
.svn
```

This file identifies files and directories that Mercurial should not attempt to put under version control, in this case all the .svn directories.

Comment: I still want to keep the svn checkout up to date. I'm assuming this will not preserve the checkout information if I want to update it. Also, I don't see `get` as of `1.6.12`.

Comment: My bad - getting commands confused, it's export, and I've edited the answer accordingly. Correct - this will get you a snapshot. Also adding to the answer...

Comment: Looks good. You could be more explicit, and say that `hg add` ignores (i.e. does not add) all files that are matched by `.hgignore`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use mercurial locally, but interact with a remote SVN repository, you can use the [hgsvn](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/hgsvn/) or [hgsubversion](https://bitbucket.org/durin42/hgsubversion/wiki/Home) extensions to push/pull changesets between the two.

Comment: Thanks, but no, I'm not trying to do that.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're trying to export a Subversion repository to Mercurial.  Try Mercurial's [convert extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/ConvertExtension).  It ships with Mercurial.  We've used it to convert between Mercurial repositories.  It will pick up where the last convert left off.  I.e., when you re-run it against an already converted repository, it will only convert commits that haven't been converted.

Comment: No, I'm just trying to convert a svn checkout to mercurial, not the repository itself.

Comment: You should still try the convert extension.  I believe it has options for converting individual revisions/commits.

Comment: Having taken a look, I don't see an obvious way to do what you suggest. Do you have a specific reference?

Comment: If its possible, you'll probably use a combination of the `--rev`  (which tells Mercurial what revision in the source system) and  `svn.startrev` arguments.  See the [ConvertExtension documentation](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/ConvertExtension).